# Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression flags

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, ajax

I can't get it,
I must have missed something..

The code looks good according to me

```
$(document).on("click", "#addo-0", function() {
    var file_data = $("#visual_image").prop("files")[0];   
    var form_data = new FormData();                  
    form_data.append("file", file_data)               
    $.ajax({
                url: "/add_file.php?table=visuals",
                dataType: "script",
                cache: false,
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                data: form_data,                         
                type: "post"
       })
```

And it works well in a way that it does the job..
But I get this nasty error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression flags
```

Did I make something wrong ? Any ideas ?

Comment: I don't see a regular expression anywhere. Which line is the error on?

Comment: @Barmar I got this VM2734:1 and this Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression flags
    at p (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Function.globalEval (jquery.min.js:2)
    at text script (jquery.min.js:4)
    at Qb (jquery.min.js:4)
    at A (jquery.min.js:4)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery.min.js:4)

Comment: when i click VM2734:1 that underline in red the print_r of my php ajax script.. So I guess it has something to do with the call

Comment: The PHP script is sending back HTML that contains JavaScript? I don't see anything in the above code that uses the response.

Comment: Did you leave out the `success:` function?

Comment: no only a move_uploaded_file( $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'] , $destination ); function

Comment: @Barmar it's possible the `dataType: 'script'` is causing jQuery to auto eval the response

Comment: "Did you leave out the success: function?" I don't have any success function..

Comment: @Taplar , when I remove the dataType, that doesn't change the error

Comment: That's it. The documentation says **Evaluates the response as JavaScript and returns it as plain text.** So if you had a `success:` function it would receive that result as an argument. But it evaluates it anyway.

Comment: In any case, the error you provided in the comments mentions `globalEval`, so the ajax is evaluating the response as javascript.  So your regexp error is within the response script

Comment: Change it to `dataType: 'text'`. It might be defaulting based on the `Content-type` of the response.

Comment: Add the response to the question, we can tell you how to fix it.

Comment: Guys that work !!!! without datatype and with success there is no errors... thanks a lot. I was struggling big time ! I don't know well that website, how can I help you back ? Do I have to tick something ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `dataType: 'script'` to `dataType: 'text'`. It's expecting the response to be valid JavaScript, even though you don't use the response.

Comment: I really feel shame spending couple of hours on this issue..... I don't delete it, It might help someone else

Comment: Barmar eluded to it in his comments, but since the issue persisted after you took off the dataType, that would seem to suggest the endpoint was putting a Content-Type on it that would cause jQuery to auto evaluate the response as a script.  If it didn't do that, you wouldn't get the error without that option.  Providing the option as 'text' forces jQuery to ignore what the server returns on the Content Type.  If possible you might want to investigate that endpoint and see if you can find anything along those lines, and determine if it is necessary. @Odjone